# Arithmetic with unsigned char

Tags: c++, math, types

Im currently implementing a RC4 decryption and as this algorithm only operates on numbers between 0-255, I want to write as safe code as possible and properly use `unsigned char` variables instead of plain `int` ones.

Well, this although confronted me with a situation i cannot fortell what will happen.

Given are 3 vars `i`, `j`, `k`:

```
unsigned char i = 150;
unsigned char j = 155;
unsigned char k = 0;
```

Will the expression `k = (i + j) % 256` properly set `k` to `49` or to `255` as `i+j` gets truncated?

Edit: fixed a "j" being spelled as "k"

Comment: `i + k` is 150, which variable have you mistyped?

Comment: There is *no sequence* of additions you can do here which would yield 50. Arithmetic on `unsigned char` is done mod 256, not mod 255.

Comment: Better use `uint8_t` or a type you define specifically to hold 8 bits. `unsigned char` contains more than 8 bits on some machines (for example 16 on TMS320C28xx).

Comment: @starblue - on machines with `unsigned char` larger than 8 bits `uint8_t` won't be defined. The unsigned 8-bit types that are **required** are `uint_least8_t` and `uint_fast8_t`. Both can be larger than 8 bits, to match the hardware architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard guarantees arithmetic on unsigned integer types to be arithmetic modulo `2^N` where `N` is the number of value bits in the type, so the arithmetic will be correct.

Section 3.9.1 (4) of the n3376 draft of the C++11 standard:

> Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where `n` is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.<sup>46)</sup>
>
> <sup>46)</sup>This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type.

Comment: That's true, but irrelevant; there isn't any truncation or overflow in the given example.

Comment: Now there is (if `CHAR_BIT == 8`), with `i = 150` and `j = 155`, `i + j` is not representable, so reduction modulo 256 occurs (won't yield 50, of course, but 49, well, it's close). It's only fixed in one place, however.

Comment: Integer promotion means that i+j produces the value 305 with type int.

Comment: But when it is assigned to an `unsigned char`, it is reduced modulo 256.